# How can I get into my device using command prompt?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, usb-debugging, oneplus-one

My OnePlus One is partially bricked. When it turns on, it does not pass the "1+ powered by android" screen. I do not know what caused this, but there is a more detailed explanation of my issue [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113450/oneplus-one-running-cm12s-is-stuck-in-boot-loop). I need to use ADB or some other recovery tool, but i had not enabled USB debugging. How can I use Command Prompt to access my device?

I really need to get my One back

Thanks

Comment: If you can boot into Recovery Mode, then try `adb shell` from there. I think stock CM recovery might have default debugging enabled, and see if you can get shell access from there.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using [OnePlusRecoveryTool](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/tool-oneplusrecovery-tool-restore-stock-cm11s-fix-bricks-etc.237827/). It revived my One when it showed no sign of revival. Note that using it would mean complete data loss. // As for PWR + Vol DN, you're supposed to boot into an environment called Recovery Mode, having some 4-5 option ranging from resetting the device, installing updates, and some others.